# How to close an app in android (with threads) called trough an intent

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent

Im kinda new to android, at this moment im calling the barcodeSCanner on my ShoplistActivity, like this:

```
Intent barcode = new Intent(ShopListActivity.this, BarcodeActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(barcode,0);
```

And then on my BarcodeActivity i have something like this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        switch (requestCode) {
        case IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE: {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
                IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(
                        requestCode, resultCode, data);

                if (scanResult != null) {

                    try {
                        setContentView(R.layout.automatico);

                        editForEAN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditEAN);
                        txt_EAN = scanResult.getContents();
                        editForEAN.setText(txt_EAN);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                    }

            }
        }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Now my problem is, that i would like to implement, with threads, a way to close the BarcodeScanner if it not used in 5s, tryed with Handler with no sucess..

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Seriously, I wouldn't do that. This is no behavior any experienced Android user would expect from their device. They would probably think that the scanner app is broken and file complaints at the wrong end. Scanning takes time sometimes. Depending on the camera and its ability and speed to autofocus. 5 seconds is simply not enough time.

Comment: I know 5s its not enought (my camera sometimes takes alot more than 5s), just wanted to try 5s for tests purpose (sry for not saying that)

Answer (score 0):

Why close it? Android apps don't need to be closed. If the user starts your app, then goes someplace else, you don't care. You do need to save your state and be prepared to re-activate when the user comes back.

In essence, the Android UX is "no exit button". Your app runs until the system throws it away to make room for something else. The only exceptions are ongoing tasks such as audio playback, and background services. In those cases you should give the user a way to stop playback or unload the service, but there's no need to stop the entire app.